# Code Igniter form validation stops script

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed a simple CMS system with Code Igniter locally with XAMPP. It was running and working, but when I deployed it to my server the script stops when I call

```
$this->form_validation->run();
```

in the following code:

```
public function check_login(){
    echo $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Benutzername', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Passwort', 'required|xss_clean');
    echo 'check';
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        echo 'check:run';
       $this->load->model('user_model');
       $username = $this->input->post('username');

       $userid = $this->user_model->get_userid_by_name($username);
       $admin = $this->user_model->is_user_admin($username);



       $userdata = array(
           'username' => $username,
           'is_admin' => $admin,
           'is_logged_in' => true,
           'user_id' => $userid
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
       redirect(base_url() . 'blog');
    } else {
        echo 'check:else';
      $this->do_login();
    }
    echo 'check:end';
}
```

The callback function is this one:

```
public function validate_credentials(){
    echo 'test';

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';

    $this->load->model('user_model'); // the script stops here
    $this->load->model('security/pass_hasher');

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $hashed_password = $this->pass_hasher->hash($password);

    echo $username . '<br />';
    echo $password . '<br />';
    echo $hashed_password . '<br />';

    print_r($this->input->post());

    if($this->user_model->can_login($username, $hashed_password)){
        if($this->user_model->is_user_active($username)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message("validate_credentials", "Benutzeraccount wurde deaktviert!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message("validate_credentials", "Benutzername und/oder Passwort ist falsch.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

For debugging reasons I made some echos. The output is the following:

> check

So the script stops running on the method I mentioned above. Why? I am autoloading `form` and `url` in the configs.
The Code Igniter enviroment is set to development. And the PHP version on my local machine is 5.4.4 and on the web server is it 5.3.8, both are newer than the required 5.1.6

When I manually post data to my `validate_credentials()` function, I get the following output:

```
test
```

```
Array
(
    [username] => admin
    [password] => test
)
```

So the $this->input->post() is not working. But I did not find out why yet.

Comment: Add `var_dump($this->form_validation->run());die();` after `echo 'check';` and see what it wields.

Comment: See error.log on your server.

Comment: Why do `echo $this->load->library('form_validation');`, `$this->load->library('form_validation');` would be fine. I doubt this may be the tweak.

Comment: @Saravanan nope, that's not it. Just tested it and it is the same as writing `echo NULL;`. I suspect that it has more to do with invalid validation callback name.

Comment: @NorthBridge, you are right.

Comment: Removed the echo, still not working (Forgot to remove it). The var_dump does not print out anything. If I remove the callback, I get the "check:run". So there might be the problem

Comment: Updated the post, I added the function to check the credentials and another output

Comment: You could try to put a `die('test')` statement at each line of `validate_credentials()`, then if you see 'test' outputted, do the same on the next line, and so on. Sooner or later you will pin down the problem and see what causes it. CodeIgniter can be very fragile and just freak out sometimes when it doesn't like something.

Comment: have you code error reporting turned on? because it sounds like there is an error occurring somewhere and that is why it is breaking. Check your index.php and make sure `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is set correctly

Comment: Error reporting is on, there is no error. I updated the description, the script stops at $this->load->model()